# Display the list element from right to left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to arrange the list element displayed from right to left,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul>
            <li>Javasript
                <ul>
                    <li>DOM</li>
                    <li>BOM</li>
                    <li>Global Objects</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>jQuery</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>HTML</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add `class="pull-right"` to ul element, but found that they were all right-alighned without formatting.

Should I adjust the padding of li one by one?

I want it shown as

> ```
>                                - Javascript
>                              - DOM
>                              - BOM
>                                  - jQuery
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgot to add bootstrap css cdn in your file. You can get bootstrap css from [here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Then you can use bootstrap grid. There is row class in bootstrap. It has 12 column. click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) for understand grid concept.

`pull-right` is replaced with `float-right`.
Similarly `pull-left`is replaced with `float-left`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul>
            <li>Javasript
                <ul>
                    <li>DOM</li>
                    <li>BOM</li>
                    <li>Global Objects</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>jQuery</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>HTML</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:- As per your question output is updated. In that, There could be multiple solutions come across. One of the solutions is you can use grid concept as I mentioned above. Identify the columns in which you would like to display content as I update in my code. Other than this you could use `align-item` as well of bootstrap. Other than this you can also use `justify-content-center` [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

Comment: thank you I accepted, but I want it shown as ( I added it to the question)

Comment: @Humbler I have update some content in the answer. Please gone threw it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS code:

```
ul{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: ty, it's a magic, I will upvote you later when accumulated enough reputations.